# How display month(s)-long data per day?

Tags: excel

I have an amount of data sort per date (e.g : 2013-12-12 10:51:51.000) and I want to display that data on a day-long plot : The plot will show the sum values or the % for each hours of the day from 0:00 to 23:59.
My problem is I don't know how to sort data "modulus day", since the date is store in one cell and so day and hours are not separates.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` in Excel cell is stored as a decimal, where integer part corresponds to Date and decimal to time after midnight, so for example 6/30/2014 9:00 is essentially equal 41820.38. Thus, the sorting should work perfectly fine: it will be using underlying numeric representation of Date and Time as explained above.

Pertinent to your further requirement, i.e. to sort only on time part (decimal) ignoring Date (integer) the solution might be as following: Assuming Date is stored in Column A (cell A1 for example), put a formula in Column B (cell B1)

```
=A1-INT(A1)
```

and extend it to entire range, then sort on Column B. Optionally, for your convenience, you can convert the cell format in Column B to **Number** (to view just decimal part).

Rgds,

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do you sort numbers only looking at their decimal part ?

Comment: Obviously, if Integer part is equal (same Date), then all values will be sorted on their decimal part. Rgds,

Comment: It won't be, because I want to sort the hours (so the decimal part) regardless of the day.